# Why do I get "Unable to cast value to object" when running this function in a remote event?

Tags: lua, roblox

When I run this code, an error occurs saying "Unable to cast value to object" on line 49 (giveOre:FireClient(oreType.Value)), even though oreType is classified as a StringValue.

```
    function mineOre(plr, target, objTool)
if not target.ClassName == "Model" then --// try to find if target is valid, else set target as target's parent (confusing prob for someone)
    target = target.Parent
end

local oreFolder = target:FindFirstChild("OreStats")
if oreFolder then
    --// Identify ore key vals
    local oreHP = oreFolder:FindFirstChild("OreHP")
    local oreLVL = oreFolder:FindFirstChild("OreLVL")

    local toolLVL = objTool.stats:FindFirstChild("LVL")
    if toolLVL and oreLVL then
        local _math = toolLVL.Value - oreLVL.Value
        if _math >= 0 then
            local toolDMG = objTool.stats:FindFirstChild("DMG")
            oreHP.Value = oreHP.Value - toolDMG.Value

            --// Check if oreHP is 0 or less
            if oreHP.Value <= 0 then
                local oreType = oreFolder:FindFirstChild("OreType")
                local giveOre = plr.Backpack:FindFirstChild("GiveORE")
                giveOre:FireClient(oreType.Value) --// Give the player the ore.

                pcall(function()
                    delay(0.1, function() target:Destroy() end)
                end)
            end
        end
    end
end
    end
```

This is the event it fires on the client in case it is needed

```
    function findSec()
local secs = {}

local toSearch = game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer.PlayerGui:WaitForChild("Backpack").Area.Inv:GetChildren()
for i,v in pairs(toSearch) do
    local ocu = v:FindFirstChild("Occupied")
    local lock = v:FindFirstChild("Locked")

    if ocu.Value == false and lock.Value == false then
        table.insert(secs, v)
    end
end
end

function giveOre(oreType)
local sec = findSec()
local toSet = sec[1]

toSet.Occupied = true
toSet.Locked = true
toSet.Ore = oreType
end

rem.OnClientEvent:connect(function(oreType)
giveOre(oreType)
end)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that RemoteEvent:FireClient() requires the first parameter to be the client you're sending it to. You get the error because you try to send a String where the program expects a Player-instance.
Correct code would be

```
giveOre:FireClient(plr, oreType.Value)
```